# Turtles won't go back to home beach to lay eggs

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been trying to obtain some turtle eggs (got silk touch on my pickaxe) to get them at my home base for my home beach, however, I keep feeding the turtles sea grass, one does get fatter and I get the XP but whenever they swim off and I follow them (and I've followed several for over an hour) they do nothing but swim aimlessly, and sometimes in circles.. it's not an area I've been before so I haven't destroyed anything and they're free to go as they please.. can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? It's super frustrating~